# javascript not showing image in imgsrc

Tags: javascript

i am using javascript to change the value of img src at run time..
i am using fileupload in html to take the input from use and i want that image to be uploaded in the "Image1" image tag.. but it is not uploading the image..
i am using:

```
 function upl(obj) {                 

                    filename = obj.value;
                    alert(filename);            
                    document.getElementById('Image1').src = '"' + filename + '"';
                    alert(document.getElementById('Image1').src);               
                    }
```

in the alert it is showing image name along with the local url..
where i am calling upl() onchange of fileupload.
can someone help me out..
thanks..

Comment: my markup is: <input type="file" id="uplfile" style="visibility:visible" onchange="upl(this);" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the " and than try to check.

like as below

```
function upl(obj) {                 

                    filename = obj.value;
                    alert(filename);            
                    document.getElementById('Image1').src =  filename;
                    alert(document.getElementById('Image1').src);               
                    }
```

Comment: @pranay rana: na its not working. filename + '' is showing imagename along with local host path i.e "http://localhost:1061/images6.jpeg" as i select image6.jpeg

Comment: So fist upload file on your server.. than pass the relative path or the path of the image location to the image src...

Comment: @pranay rana: the file that i am giving ito it is already uploaded. if i give static filename, it will upload the file ..

Comment: first copy the path "http://servername/img.ext"  and past it in the next browser window ...is it showing image over there ?

Comment: @pranay rana: by giving "image6.jpg" its working, but i want to take the input from user in fileupload control and that image i want to show..

Comment: i must say you are assigning the wrong path.......you need to check the path you are assigning is working when you past it in the new browser window...........your path must be "http://server/dirctory/img.ext" not like "http://servername/img.ext"

Comment: @pranay rana: is there any way to save image on server using javascipt.

Comment: no you cannot do it with the javascript ...you need to user serverside lang to do it ....or may be with the help of ajax you can do it but ajax calls server side lang only

Answer (score 1):

Try with `setAttribute`:

```
document.getElementById('Image1').setAttribute('src', 'http://www.uploadarchief.net/files/download/troll_face.jpg');
```

Comment: that worked fine, but is there any way to save image on server using javascript..